# What happened to my frozen yeast?

Tags: yeast, frozen, spoilage, smell

I had a leftover block of commercially bought frozen yeast. I kept it it the freezer, well below 0 celsius. I'll admit I didn't check on it for years.

I opened the container today. It was stinking like nothing I've ever seen. But it was also... liquid ? What on earth happened ? It stank so much, I just threw it all away without taking pictures or anything. But I now wonder, is this alive enough to generate enough heat to thaw itself ? What processes were going on ? Is this a typical/known issue ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TIL that there are organisms which not only survive temperatures under 0 Celsius, but are able to actively live in that range, as opposed to just hibernating. Nevertheless, I doubt that baker's yeast falls under them - it is the kind of factoid one would expect to read in popular books on food science. Also, it is unlikely that something adapted for life under such conditions would be most vigorous at +35ish, as yeast is.

My guess is that it thawed in much more prosaic manner. You either had a power outage that you were not aware of, or the cumulative effect of years of self-defrosting cycles was sufficient to enable several generations of proliferation.

You describe it as being both liquid and stinky - this sounds like they produced stuff and they suffocated in it, just like in overfermented dough. It would have been mostly ethanol, but mixed with other waste compounds. A pure water-ethanol mixture created by yeast won't freeze (it shouldn't go above the alcohol content of wine), but it is not outlandish that, with enough other molecules swimming around, the whole mixture was not frozen solid at slightly below zero. So once their "civilization" had multiplied enough to drown in its own waste, it may have stayed liquid, even though it was in the freezer. Also, for such a long period of time, some enzymatic reactions might have happened even at those unlikely temperatures, leading to further decay.

Bottom line, it seems that the yeast had an opportunity to multiply (at above zero) and took it.

Comment: From personal experience, I find that yeast quality decreases considerably after three months in the freezers.

Comment: There's actually a whole bunch of organisms that live below 0C, but none that are relevant for this question.

Comment: @FuzzyChef : but if there was contamination (it was a "leftover block"), those other organisms may have been present and eaten the yeast or the medium in there to support it

Comment: Joe: the organisms that can live below freezing are generally speaking from the deep sea and the antarctic.  While contamination of yeast with those might be *possible*, it's not *likely*.

Comment: *A pure water-ethanol mixture created by yeast won't freeze (it shouldn't go above the alcohol content of wine)* but note that (red) wine still flows in a domestic freezer despite appearing almost solid, so the alcohol content is almost enough; any contaminants would probably suppress the freezing point still further.

Comment: ...Also some of the water would end up bound; perhaps freeze-thaw cycles concentrated the alcohol after the yeast was dead or inert. With no sugar and the cold retarding its metabolism, but plenty of oxygen (for that low metabolic rate anyway) the yeast will behave in interesting ways.  Could some of the the stink have been vinegary I wonder - some acetic acid would be expected? The hooch on a sourdough starter is mostly yeast-produced alcohol (and water) but doesn't smell like beer

Comment: @ChrisH indeed, now that I looked the exact numbers up, a pure water-ethanol mixture at 10-20% should freeze between -4 and -9 C. I don't know what exact compounds would have been produced by a dying yeast colony, but I think your intuition and mine are aligned - it is not surprising that, once the fermentation had happened, the result stayed liquid while the freezer was working normally and keeping other food frozen.